# unpacking a string with list comprehension python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, poker, argument-unpacking

I got the following code.

```
hand = '6C 7C 8C 9C TC'.split()
```

so hand is now a list of strings  `['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC']`

then

```
ranks = ["--23456789TJKA".index(r) for r, s in hand]
```

ranks is now `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

The aim is to give card's rank the proper numeric value to allow sorting it: 
i.e. 'T'->10, 'J'->11, 'Q'-12, 'K'->13 and 'A'->14.

I don't understand why it works!

- to get an item from a list is `list[item]`
- to slice a string is `"string"[0]`

I do not see it in the ranks list comprehension.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Every element of hand is a string with two characters.

In time of forming `ranks`, what you are doing is for each element of `hand`, unpacking the string to two separate variable.

So, in the variable `r`, you will get

```
6 7 8 9 T ...
```

And, in variable `s`, you will get:

```
C C C C C ....
```

Let's see this.

```
[(r,s) for r, s in hand]
```

Output:

```
[('6', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('9', 'C'), ('T', 'C')]
```

And you are forming the list `ranks` with the index of each of `r` in the string `--23456789TJKA`

Let's see how this works:

```
>>"--23456789TJKA".index('6')
>> 6
>>"--23456789TJKA".index('7')
>> 7
>>"--23456789TJKA".index('8')
>> 8
```

And so on!

Answer (score 0):

Check what `[(r,s) for r, s in hand]` gives you. It's

```
[('6', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('9', 'C'), ('T', 'C')]
```

This is because you unpack your 2-letter strings into `r` and `s` (each string is an iterable).

So when you do `index(r)`, you're searching for the index of the first character only.

Answer (score 0):

Strings, like lists, can be iterated through. For example:

```
>>> for s in 'string':
...     print s
... 
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

Hence, when you're doing `for r, s in hand` , it does:

```
r = '6'
s = 'C'
```

For each item (obviously a different value for each item)

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot the unpacking method.

Comment: @RalphV.L No problem! Be sure to accept the answer by clicking the tick under my score :)

Answer (score 0):

You're starting with:

```
>>> hand = ['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC']
```

So consider what happens when you do this:

```
>>> [(r, s) for r, s in hand]
[('6', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('9', 'C'), ('T', 'C')]
```

The `for r, s in hand` bit splits each *two*-character long string into `r` and `s`, then puts them together in a tuple. Your code is a little different in that it doesn't put them into a tuple, it just uses the `r` as the argument to the `index` function.